# Does vite has Provide plugin like wepback?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vite

I have vue2 app with webpack and i want to move it to vite. But i cant provide vue globally.

For example i have this code snippet

```
new Vue({
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    el: '#app',
});
```

If i run `vite build` - it's not compile vue to js like if i'll add **vue import**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
            
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  el: '#app',
});
```

i'v tried to add

```
 plugins: [
        vue(),
 ],
```

or

```
rollupOptions: {
   external: ['vue'],
   ...
}
```

or add globals

```
output: {
    globals: {
    vue: 'Vue',
  }
}
```

But all of this not working. So how i can use vite like webpack with ProvidePlugin

Comment: I think you need @rollup/plugin-inject, if what you want is to make vue globally available

Comment: thx it rly works